# Excel VBA: Is there a dynamic Array that can be used for Dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel Macro and I want to create an array of dates and then loop through it, without knowing how many dates will be added. I thought this would be simple, but I can't get it to work.

I tried using a collection:

```
Dim DateArr As Collection
Dim d As Date

Set DateArr = New Collection

DateArr.Add (CDate("1/1/2019"))
DateArr.Add (CDate("2/2/2020"))

For Each d In DateArr
    sh.Cells(y, 27).Value = d
Next d
```

But I get an error that says "For Each control variable must be Variant or Object" and highlights the d in my loop. Are dates not objects?

I also tried a Variant:

```
Dim DateArr As Variant
DateArr.Add CDate("2/2/2020")
DateArr(1) = CDate("1/1/2019")
```

But I can't find the right syntax for adding a Date. The .Add line gives me an "Object Required" error and the DateArr(1)= line gives me a "Type Mismatch" error.

The only thing that kind of works is a standard array:

```
Dim DateArr() As Date
Dim y As Integer
ReDim DateArr(1 To 2) As Date

DateArr(1) = CDate("1/1/2019")
DateArr(2) = CDate("2/2/2020")

For y = LBound(DateArr) To UBound(DateArr)
    sh.Cells(y, 27).Value = DateArr(y)
Next y
```

But I have no idea how many dates will be in the array, so can't use anything static. Is there a way to use this same syntax without setting dimensions?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use Collections and then change `d` to a Variant.

Comment: You might just want to use somethign like `sh.Cells(y, 27).Value = Format(DateArr(y),"yyyy-mm-dd")`.  How will you be pulling the information?  Manually adding dates in the code, pulling from a range in a sheet, etc.?

Comment: @BrianMStafford, that works! At least for my little test example. Fingers crossed it works for my main goal.

Comment: @Cyril, I could have been more clear that this was just a test case. My actual use case is: I have a spreadsheet of people and the weekends where they will be on call. I'm trying to loop through every line, create a object (custom class) for each person and then store their on call dates in a collection associated with my class and do some logic on the dates. I got stuck when I couldn't create a collection of dates.

Comment: @JamesDolan if you treat this like a standard array, you can just capture all of the range, e.g. `dim arr as variant` // `arr = range(cells(1,1),cells(lr,3)).value`.  You should be retaining the original date as a date, regardless of appending that data elsewhere or using it in formulae.  You shouldn't need to loop to create the array, unless you're looking to make a dictionary for unique dates.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are variants not objects

Add for collections is a method.  In your code you have assumed it is a function and added unnecessary parentheses, e.g.

```
DateArr.add cdate("1/1/2019")
```

To use a For Each then the indexing (controlling) variable must be an object or a variant.

Thus your first example should work fine (other errors not withstanding) if you dim d as a variant.